# Transitivity property of String comparison in java

Tags: java, string, comparator, compareto, timsort

take a look at this code

```
   class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

     @Override
     public int compare(String a, String b) {
         if (a.length() == b.length()) {
             return b.compareTo(a);
         } else {
             String ab = a + b;
             String ba = b + a;
             return ba.compareTo(ab);
         }
     }
 }
```

ba.compareTo(ab) works but ab.compareTo(ba) fails. It throws an IllegalArgumentException citing a violation of the comparator contract. I believe its due to the fact that the transitivity property was not satisfied. Can someone please explain how Java uses the transitivity property in case of Strings ? Does this have anything to do with how Timsort works ?

EDIT: Here is the error i get on the Leetcode online judge

```
Runtime Error Message:
                Line 32: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!




              Last executed input:
                [7286,155,351,6059,9686,2668,9551,5410,7182,170,3746,3095,8139,2587,2351,2341,2038,3956,6034,4071,9473,281,9306,8746,7954,8937,7855,3938,9737,2455,4344,2986,8968,1072,2442,7191,9106,4236,2768,5214,7541,329,7530,9068,9644,3539,5177,5332,2065,8245,7494,8454,604,4632,1745,301,3412,1569,8637,7840,7752,9536,1023,4841,1286,6489,8459,2725,8021,5026,7058,4540,9892,5344,1205,4363,959,9729,9225,9733,8417,9873,3721,1434,5136,6111,6189,780,4741,2670,2457,5424,1040,3746,1229,8568,3636,1546,2553,575]
```

Again, i dont get this error when i use ba.compareTo(ab). I

Comment: How does actually `ab.compareTo(ba)` fail? What's your input?

Comment: i am trying to compare int after converting them to strings. i am trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/

Comment: Why don't you compare integers and then use a string just as an accumulator building the result? (compare ints, append the bigger to the string/stringbuilder)

Comment: nice idea. though i am still curious as to why "93".compareTo("39") is valid but "39".compareTo("93") is not ?

Comment: `System.out.println("39".compareTo("93"))` prints `-6`. What do you mean by not valid?

Comment: hmm... correct. i wonder why the online judge threw the exception when i tried ab.compareTo(ba) instead of ba.compareTo(ab) ? any idea how transitivity property is handled in Java ?maybe it was failing due to some complex input from the online judge.

Comment: if i use ab.compareTo(ba) i end up with the smallest number. which is intuitive and makes sense. i guess the online judge must have used a weird input that threw the comparator off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `compare` doesn't seem to respect the transitive property if `a` and `b` have different lengths.

This is the [Comparator.compare(a,b) contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)), see the bold part regarding transitivity:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second. In the foregoing description, the
>   notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function,
>   which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the
>   value of expression is negative, zero or positive.
>
> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y,
>   x)) for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an
>   exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)
>
> **The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
>   ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0**.
>
> **Finally, the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies
>   that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.**
>
> It is generally the case, but not strictly required that (compare(x,
>   y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any comparator that
>   violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The
>   recommended language is "Note: this comparator imposes orderings that
>   are inconsistent with equals."

*Update:*

Just to add an interesting side-note, you refer to Tim sort as the sorting algorithm applied by Collections.sort(),etc... , for smaller arrays (size under an hard-coded threshold), a simple merge sort is performed instead. The choice is made at the beginning of the sort method, see openJDK sources for more info.

Comment: thanks, but why does it fail for lets say "3" and "9"
why is "93".compareTo("39") valid but "39".compareTo("93") is not ?

Comment: It's a consequence of the sort algorithm being used, that is chosen depending on the size of the input (see the openjdk sources to see this) , can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Because it could be Timsort but also mergesort if the number of elements is small enough (it's an hard-coded constant, less than 10 if i remember correctly).

Comment: correct. for primitive types, it breaks the collection into pieces of size 7 or smaller. each individual piece is sorted by insertion sort and then the results are merged.

Comment: on your comment Y'es, your compare doesn't seem to respect the transitive property if a and b have different lengths' : why does the method work for ba.compareTo(ab) ? ant for ab.compareTo(ba) ?

Comment: Also @user2334092, thinking about what you wrote, there is another important thing,  that compare method is just wrong, because you are performing a lexical comparison. Your `compare("39","93")` returns `-6` that would seem correct, BUT `compare("39","930")` returns the same `-6`, completely **wrong** and definitely not what you want.

Comment: why would that be wrong ? 39 should be smaller than 930 right ? additionally, for this comparator, ba and ab would be of the same length.

Comment: Sorry took the wrong one, i meant `compare("390","93")` returns `6` as does `compare("39","93")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have three numbers in string format a, b, and c and `a | b | c` is the largest result can be obtained.

then we know `(a | b) > (b | a)` and `(b | c) > (c | b)`.

Assume `(c | a) > (a | c)` (no transitivity), then we have:

`(c | a | b) > (a | c | b) > (a | b | c)`. This contradicts `a | b | c` is the largest.